# How to build a dicom database

Tags: php, mysql, dicom

language: `php` database: `mysql`.

I have searched for some files about dicom database, but it just doesn't tell me a simple example.

Here are some I summarized: 
simple database 5 tables:

1. patient(patientid to be the major key)
2. study(study instance UID to be the major key)
3. series(series instance UID to be the major key)
4. image(image instance UID to be the major key)
5. link the four tables'major key and write into this table, and of course the `.dcm` files will be stored in the server folder

So do I need to modify somewhere if you think it's wrong? Are there some key data I've already missed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The patient id is not proper key, because it is not an unique identifier.

Study, Series, Image UID are unique and would work as key, but in view of performance it is may be not the best choice, because it is simply a too long string.

You should think about an internal assigned (auto-incremental) key.

Comment: sorry to answer you so late, I just don't  understand what is the internal assigned (auto-incremental) key,may you explain it to me ?

Comment: some databases support an auto-incremental field, which continuously increments e.g. by 1 with a new entry.

Comment: I konw but I can't understand why we should choose this kind of way to build the database

Comment: Well, searching the database by an `int` type is much faster than searching for a long string like the study, series or image UID. If this is not essential to you, than you can of course use the UIDs.

Comment: You may also check the [database table description from dcm4che](https://dcm4che.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ee2/Database+Table+Descriptions) , it is a good example.